# Pyenv VirtualEnv - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyenv

I am getting error message like below every time I am trying to install virtualenv version higher then 2.7.12. I tried almost everything, even reinstall of pyenv&virtualenv did not help me. I am beginner of python but i think there is a problem with pip.

I noticed my system is missing some libraries but its senseless to install them all one by one.

```
konrad@konrad-VPCEB2S1E:~/.pyenv/versions$ pyenv virtualenv 3.0.1 VirtualEnv_3.0.1
New python executable in /home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/envs/VirtualEnv_3.0.1/bin/python3.0
Also creating executable in /home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/envs/VirtualEnv_3.0.1/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/konrad/.pyenv/..._3.0.1/bin/python3.0 - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 15, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name OrderedDict

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ordered_dict.py", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named thread

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/_collections.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/ordered_dict.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dummy_thread

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==15.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/home/konrad/.pyenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/python3.0/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/konrad/.pyenv/..._3.0.1/bin/python3.0 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Comment: Do you really use python 3.0? It's outdated, upgrade to at least python 3.3.

Comment: Its not about which version of python I am using. I need to make project using 3.0.1 version.  I have installed version 3.3 using pyenv and all went well during instalation. The only problem is with 3.0.1 Version. I am still wondering what is wrong.

Comment: [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) works with Python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.3+. Not with 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2.